# mvc 3: disabling validation on selected fields

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery-validate

I have a need to disable validation on certain fields when certain events occur, so based on the suggestion in this thread: [jQuery disable rule validation on a single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853416/jquery-disable-rule-validation-on-a-single-field)

I tried this:

```
$("form").validate({
   ignore: ".ignore"
})
```

But I am finding that it disables all validation on all fields, not just those with class="ignore".

Am I doing something wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying:

```
$('#CompaniesGridform').validate({
    ignore: ":disabled"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing it something like this

```
<button id="Submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Submit").on("click", function () {
        var validator = $("form").data('validator');
        validator.settings.ignore = ".ignore";
    });
</script>
```

Switch out .ignore for any jQuery selector or chain them up like ".ignore, input[type=hidden]"