# jQuery validation & ignore field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I have a form with id `myform` and two fields (dates) with `date` class.
I would like to avoid jquery.validation (unobstrusive jquery validation on ASP .NET MVC3) for these two fields. I tried :

```
    $('#myform').validate({
        ignore: ".date"
    });
```

However it doesn't work, I always have an error (`Please enter a valid date.`).

I need help please !

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js include by default in ASP .NET MVC3 project.

Comment: Is it possible that whatever datetimepicker widget you are using is dynamically creating new controls, which aren't getting ignored?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need `ignoreTitle`, according to [This Doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate).

Comment: Wait... what?  The doc doesn't say that's what 'ignoreTitle` does.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 5):

It works fine to me as described at the documentation http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ".ignore"
});
```

And, for multiple field use:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ".ignore, .another_class"
});
```

Comment: Warning, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853416/jquery-disable-rule-validation-on-a-single-field regarding ".ignore, :hidden"

Comment: Does it also work on text fields? (I.e., input type="text".) I can't get it to work for those, and if I debug the code, it seems it only checks for the ignore field if an element is "checkable" (i.e. radio or checkbox).

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is trying this alongside `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`, you may find it's ignoring all options passed into `$("#myform").validate()` and you'll have to set them on the object instead:

```
$('#myform').validate().settings.ignore = ".date";
$('#myform').valid();
```

The Unobtrusive plugin calls `validate()` when the document loads, which sets the options to defaults. A validator will then be created and cached, and any further calls to `validate()` will ignore new options and return the cached validator.