# mvc stop clientside validation on a certain field?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have the following property in my model:

```
    [DisplayName("Pay to RE Date")]
    public DateTime? PaymentToRE { get; set; }
```

Whenever I type in something that is not a valid date, I get the message:

```
The value 'asdas' is not valid for Pay to RE Date.
```

I however, did not want validation happening at this point, as I have other properties which I need to validate and want all to validate together.  The others require me to look up information in the database, so I did not want client side validation on this field.  Is there anyway to disable it?

This is used in my view as below:

```
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentToRE, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @{Html.EnableClientValidation(false);}
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PaymentToRE, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker-input form-control" })
                @{Html.EnableClientValidation(true);}
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentToRE)
            </div>
```

I tried using the Html.EnableClientValidation method, but that doesn't seem to stop it.  And I didn't want to disable ClientValidation for the entire application as I need it on other forms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery disable rule validation on a single field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853416/jquery-disable-rule-validation-on-a-single-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using jQuery validation plugin. You can use its option `ignore`. http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore

Add a ignore class to you textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PaymentToRE, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker-input form-control no-client-validation" })
```

And add to jQuery validation option `ignore` the new class `no-client-validation`:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: '.no-client-validation, :hidden' //:hidden is default value
});
```

**EDIT**

Or you switch to remote validation, might be overhead in your case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28vs.98%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    $('form').validate({
        ignore:"#PaymentToRE"
    });
```

The validate plugin will ignore the input with `id=PaymentToRE`

Answer (score -2):

You can't assign string value in DateTime property change your property to this

```
[DisplayName("Pay to RE Date")]
public String PaymentToRE { get; set; }
```

Comment: He's not asking about converting any value, he just wants to disable client validation for a certain property.

Comment: @Simon The solution I told is the only way, I have faced this problem and that's why I know.

Comment: Seriously, I don't know what your problem is but OPs problem is definitely not the same. And by the way, I am using jQuery validation option `ignore` and that is working very well...