# C# No validation when Hidden Field

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The following code should ignore any validation fields with the class `ignore`

With the HTML helper I added the class `ignore`, but whenever I press submit it will still want validation, even though the class `ignore` is added.

According to: [jQuery disable rule validation on a single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853416/jquery-disable-rule-validation-on-a-single-field)
The following jQuery should disable any validation on fields with the class `ignore` however that does not work.

**jQuery**

```
function hideBel() {
    $('#BelBep').hide();
    $('#iqform').validate(
       { ignore: ".ignore, :hidden"
    })
};
```

**create.cshtml**

```
<fieldset id="iqform">
    <legend>Form</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BevBeleid) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BevBeleid)</div>
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.BevBeleid, "true", new { onclick = "showBel();"}) Ja</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.BevBeleid, "false", new { onclick = "hideBel();" }) Nee</label>

    <div id="BelBep" style="display: none;">
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BelLastName)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BelLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "ignore"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BelLastName)
        </div>

    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this ignore behavior we should add required selectors to jQuery-validation-defaults.
As we know `:hidden` is by default, here we're adding `.ignore` CssClass selector as shown below.

How and where this defaults script should place in the code file.

> I'm doing like below in **myview.cshtml** file

```
<!--HTML and Razor markup -->
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        //Below defaults setting should run 
        //after jquery.validation js execution and before DOM-Ready.
        //Note: This script block placement must be after below script embed tags
        //jquery.validate.min.js,jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js(=>jqueryval bundle)
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: ':hidden, .ignore'
        });
        $(function () {
            //Script to Run after DOM-Ready
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Hmm, do i replace the $('#iqform').validate?
or do i add that to my function, or make a seperate function. please extend it a bit!

Comment: I tried adding it to that function, also in a seperate function on document.ready, also tried doing both at the same time.. STILL asks for a validation