# How to undetect/ignore javascript events in a certain html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this line of code `$('#tbl-purchase-list').on( 'keyup change', 'input[type="text"]'` that detects the input of all `input[type="text"]` field. However, I have an input field that I dont want to be detected when inputting a text on the keyboard or make any changes on it.`<input type="text" class="form-control purchase-freight-charge" id="purchase-freight-charge" value=""  />`. Is there a way in javascript that ignores certain events for a certain element? Something like this `$("#purchase-freight-charge").ignoreEvents();`? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery disable rule validation on a single field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853416/jquery-disable-rule-validation-on-a-single-field)

Comment: The [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse there is a `:not()` Pseudo selector:

```
$('#tbl-purchase-list').on('keyup change', 
                           'input[type="text"]:not(#purchase-freight-charge)', 
                           ...);
```

It will not add the target element in the matched set of selectors. So, there won't be any event for that element which is inside `:not()`.

Event this can also be done:

```
$('#tbl-purchase-list').on('keyup change', 'input[type="text"]',function(ev){
     if(this.id === "purchase-freight-charge"){
        this.value = "";
     }
});
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this approach with event.stopImmediatePropagation();?

Comment: For that you have to bind another event on a selector. Here in this case you just have to work at a single place. One more thing you can do...updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/):

```
$("#purchase-freight-charge").on('keyup change', function( event ) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

// Future event bindings won't be executed for #purchase-freight-charge
// ...
```