# Ignore validation for an element html - Jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've a form look like this:

```
<form action="..." name="editPost">
    <div class="main">
     <input type="text">
     <input type="text">
     <input type="text">
     <input type="text">
     <input type="text">
    </div>

    <ul class="form_template">
        <li><input type="text" id="question1"></li>
        <li><input type="text" id="question2"></li>
        <li><input type="text" id="question3"></li>
        <li><input type="text" id="question4"></li>
        <li><input type="text" id="question5"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

my js code is:

```
var validator = $("form[name='editPost']").validate();
```

and My goal is **only** validate `main` id fields and the rest doesn't validate.

And finally, my question is **how to ignore validation** for `form_template` class

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853429/2397327

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ignore` attribute only works with inputs, You can do a regular expression to ignore a set of inputs, but the conditions is that its names starts with the same name, for example, you have several fields like these:

```
        <input type="text" required="required" name="h1" id="goal1">
        <input type="text" required="required" name="h2" id="goal2">
        <input type="text" required="required" name="h3" id="goal3">
        <input type="text" required="required" name="h4" id="goal4">
        <input type="text" required="required" name="h5" id="goal5">
```

Watch out `id` attr, it starts with the same string, but it really are differents, finally config `ignore` attr like this:

```
            $("form[name='editPost']").validate({
               ignore: "input[id^='goal']"
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ignore` property in the config object for the validation.

```
$("form[name='editPost']").validate({
   ignore: ".form_template"
});
```

Source: [jQuery Validation Plugin docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/): see `ignore` option.